# Simple Mybatis, how to obtain a collection?

Tags: mybatis

It has been a long time since I have done this, and I simply cannot see the pattern to code MyBatis to get a collection, after spending a lot of time searching the examples and Mybatis docs.

The problem I have is with the examples and answers lacking the code to interpret it properly, understand, and integrate into my own code... or it simply does not work, returning this error (in most cases):

> org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.TooManyResultsException: Expected one
>   result (or null) to be returned by selectOne(), but found: 3

I have simplified the query and everything else I am trying to accomplish. What I need is a mapper in XML format as well as the Java interface, as a simple and a plain example that works ...

SQL statement I am trying to execute:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable;
```

The structure of the MyTable

```
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 | a     |
|  2 | ab    |
|  3 | abc   |
+----+-------+
```

The model is:

```
public class MyTable{
     private short id = 0;
     private String value;

public short getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(short id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}
}
```

What I need to obtain is a

```
List<MyTable>
```

I am aware that there are similar questions, however, neither is providing the answer in xml format for the mapper, or the answers are not easy to understand lacking the code to support the answer ... Therefore, I want to keep this as simple as possible, for anyone else trying to connect things without a success.

Comment: The error `TooManyResultsException` is relatively easy to fix. Please show us MyBatis related code i.e. 1) XML statement, 2) Java mapper interface (if there is) and 3) Java code calling the statement when that happens.

Comment: @ave this is a relatively simple example, and I would prefer to start with a new example provided within the stack overflow. Reason, like I said, I tried too many different examples.

Answer (score 1):

With the limited information provided, all I can show you is a super simple example.

test/Mapper.xml

```xml
<mapper namespace="test.Mapper">
  <select id="selectAll" resultType="MyTable">
    select * from MyTable
  </select>
</mapper>
```

test/Mapper.java

```java
package test;

import java.util.List;

public interface Mapper {
  List<MyTable> selectAll();
}
```

```java
try (SqlSession sqlSession = sqlSessionFactory.openSession()) {
  Mapper mapper = sqlSession.getMapper(Mapper.class);
  List<MyTable> list = mapper.selectAll();
}
```

Here is an executable [demo project](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/so-59546191/so-59546191).